# How does ODBC determine what functions a driver supports?

Tags: c++, windows, odbc

I am debugging an ODBC driver and came across the following entry in the ODBC LOG

```
crw32           7e0-235c    ENTER SQLGetInfoW 
        HDBC                0x03816BE0
        UWORD                        6 <SQL_DRIVER_NAME>
        PTR                 0x0180EB18 
        SWORD                      256 
        SWORD *             0x0180E6EC

crw32           7e0-235c    EXIT  SQLGetInfoW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x03816BE0
        UWORD                        6 <SQL_DRIVER_NAME>
        PTR                 0x0180EB18 
        SWORD                      256 
        SWORD *             0x0180E6EC

        DIAG [IM001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function (0)
```

How does ODBC determine whether a driver supports a given function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ODBC API called SQLGetFunctions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is usually handled in the ODBC driver manager but an ODBC driver can supply its own. If the driver manager is handling it, then it probably just looks to see what functions are exported by the driver code.

BTW, a driver which really does not support SQLGetInfo is seriously broken.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The problem was with `SQLGetFunctions` of the driver which was incorrectly returning the functions the driver supported.